# Send data from .gsp to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, controller, gsp

I need send data from text input in .gsp page to a controller using js or ajax. My code in gsp page is

```
 <input placeholder="<g:message code="form.search.label"/>" id="q" name="q" type="text" onkeypress=validar(event);>
 <button class="button"><span class="mif-search"></span></button>
```

The js function is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function validar(event){
    var theCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
    var message = $('#q').val();
    if (theCode == 13){           
        
        <g:remoteFunction controller="search" action="search" params="message" update="pageid"/>          
}
}
```

This code work fine is I wish to refresh my page, but I need to send the data in the input text to my controller. I surf in web but I can't resolve this problem. What I need to do for this?

Comment: `<g:remoteFunction />` is not inteded for usage from javascript block. Instead one of the options is to use jQuery.ajax(). See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for examples

Comment: what version of Grails are you using? It makes a difference...

Comment: I use 2.5.3 Grails version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend use `jQuery.ajax();` instead of `g:remoteFunction` because at the end of the day. The `g:remoteFuncion` it would be rendered to `jQuery.ajax();`. For example, you have this:

```
<g:remoteFunction controller="search" action="search" params="message" update="pageid"/>
```

This will be:

```
jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', url:'/YOURGRAILSAPPNAME/search/search',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#pageid').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});
```

You can test looking the HTML in your webpage.

But if you really want to use the `g:remoteFunction`. You can use this

```
var message = $('#q').val();
if (theCode == 13)
    <g:remoteFunction controller="search" action="search" params="'message='+message" update="pageid"/>
```